# How to get get data from a json file in a Widget bundle in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, widget

I have a json file like this :

```
[
  {
    "car" : "yellow",
    "tires" : "black"
  },
  {
    "car" : "blue",
    "tires" : "brown"
  }
]
```

How do I get the data into the widget bundle? 
(having already done the CarTypes stuct) 
I have tried to use :

```
var weeks: [CarTypes] = load("cars.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

But it says that file is not in the main bundle i.e "Couldn't find cars.json in main bundle."

Comment: You need to have your `cars.json` file added to your app's target. Use the rightmost side panel in Xcode when the file is highlighted and see if your target is selected.

Comment: Tyyyy ... I thought it was somewhere there but turns out I changed the location instead of the target.